# How do I connect to a new wifi on the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All commands that should be used to connect to wifi in command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9818/all-commands-that-should-be-used-to-connect-to-wifi-in-command-line)

I don't need to configure my wifi card or anything. I just want to do the equivalent of a) listing the wifi devices in my neighbourhood, and b) connecting to one (and setting up the password for it) as I do in the GUI.

Surely there's a command-line command for this?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9818/all-commands-that-should-be-used-to-connect-to-wifi-in-command-line

Comment: Surely there's something simpler than the answer in that question?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume `wlan0` is the name of your wireless device.

1. Bring the device up: `ifconfig wlan0 up`.
2. List the wireless networks with `iwlist wlan0 scan | less` and find the network you want to connect to.
3. Use `wpa_supplicant` to associate and connect with the network.

   a) Create a config file for `wpa_supplicant`, containing encryption information about the network. See `man wpa_supplicant.conf` for examples. Try with simplest entries first.

   b) Run `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` (as root; assuming `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` is the name of the config file).  If it works, run it in the background and redirect the output somewhere (I just dump it to `/dev/null`.)
4. Use `dhclient wlan0` *or* `dhcpcd wlan0` to obtain IP.
5. PROFIT!

Comment: Doesn't seem I have wpa_supplicant on my machine. :-(

Comment: Well, then just install it! You'll certainly find it in your distro's repositories.

Comment: @interstar Just type `yum install wpa_supplicant` and you will have it.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/), which has a text-mode menu-driven frontend `wicd-curses` which lists the networks and does the setting and dhcp stuff for you.

Comment: Don't seem to have wicd either.